# Web scraping different formats

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, scrape, vs-web-site-project

I'm attempting to scrape the names, email IDs (linked to their name), years, and roles/subjects of the staff on this page https://www.aacps.org/Page/4014 and save the details in an excel sheet. Running into difficulties collecting link data as well as plaintext information.

This is what I have so far:

```
url_fac='https://www.aacps.org/Page/4014'
print(url_fac)
req_fac = urllib.request.Request(url_fac, headers=hdr)
html_page_fac = urllib.request.urlopen(req_fac)
soup_fac = BeautifulSoup(html_page_fac, "lxml")
links_fac=soup_fac.find_all('a')
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way, but gets you the data in a format which can be cleaned.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}

url_fac = 'https://www.aacps.org/Page/4014'

req_fac = requests.get(url_fac, headers=headers)
soup_fac = BeautifulSoup(req_fac.content, 'html.parser')
staff_fac = soup_fac.find('div', attrs={'id': "sw-module-78060"})

for link in staff_fac.find_all('a', href=True):
   print("Url: " + link['href'])
   print("Name: " + link.parent.text)
   print("Team: " + link.parent.parent.parent.find("strong").text)
```

Output:

```
Url: mailto:shartford@aacps.org
Name: Principal – Shelley Hartford  shartford@aacps.org
Team: Principal
```

etcetera